# Return non-HTML, non-JSON http bodies in Tapestry 5?

Tags: java, oauth, tapestry

I have to implement the service provider of the OAuth protocol in a project that uses Tapestry5. Therefor I just need to return a very simple HTTP response body that is neither HTML or JSON.

At first I tried to use the standard tml & pojo (java class, page) approach but this doesn't work because Tapestry tries to parse the templates.

So I think I have to try something different. Maybe it is possible to use a render() method in a page? But I couldn't find any documentation that would answer this question.

Or should I just use another framework that would better fit my needs?

Thank you for your advice,

Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brian pushed me in the right direction, but the actual solution to the problem was even simpler:

```
StreamResponse onActivate() {
     return new TextStreamResponse("text/plain", "foo=bar");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can stream text directly from the page without using a template:

```
StreamResponse onActivate() {
  return new StreamResponse(
    public String getContentType() {
      return "text/plain";
    }

    public InputStream getStream() {
      return new ByteArrayInputStream("foo=bar".getBytes());
    }

    public void prepareResponse(Response response) {
      // response.setHeader(...
    }
}
```

If you were doing it for a lot of pages, I think you could contribute your own DocumentLinker that lets you bypass all the xml/html/head stuff that Tapestry adds to the page by default. Then you could go back to using templates.

Comment: Thank you so for hinting me in the right direction. My solution was even simpler.

Comment: Good catch - I didn't know about TextStreamResponse.